# Has my network been captcha blacklisted

Tags: network, captcha

I  usually visit a particular site and I never get captchas there. Recently, I wrote a web crawler to visit that site and do things for me. I used the crawler a lot and now I get captchas on the site. I assumed it was too much traffic and the site would get back to normal behavior later but it hasn't. I still get capcthas there every day even when I visit manually like a human on a fresh network.

Is there something causing this that I can fix?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there something casuing this ...

It is pretty common today that sites protect themselves against bot traffic. Too much bot traffic might result in IP addresses getting a bad reputation for some time. Depending on how exactly the bot protection works it might also be at the level of the user account.

> ... i can fix?

There is no single solution which is valid for all sites since there isn't a single way of how bot protections work.

If the bot protection works at the level of an IP address you might try to connect from a different IP, like using a VPN. Sometimes ISP will also assign a new IP address when reconnecting the modem, but this depends on your specific connectivity. If the protection works on the level of some user account you probably need to wait longer.

> Recently, i wrote a web crawler to visit that site and do things for me.

Better read the terms and conditions of the site before doing this. Many explicitly forbid the use of automation against their sites and many enforce such rules, no matter how well intended (in your personal opinion) your use was. This is especially true for sites were users can gain an unfair advantage against others by using automation (like gaming, bidding, buying highly desired but limited items) or were automation is used to scrape information from sites and thus undermine their business model.